# Jquery increment/decrement ticket counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a counter that allows user to select the different types of people that will be going to an event. The user will be able to "add" more of the adult when they click the number and when they click minus it will reduce the number by 1, this is supposed to work together with the other two ticket types (student,senior).

So if there are 2 adults, there can only be one student one senior or two senior etc. Currently I am able to increment the counter but unable to disable the decrement when i click minus.

```js
var quantity = 4;
var number = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.num', function() {
  number++;
  if (number <= quantity) {
    $(this).text(number)
  } else {
    number--;
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.fa-minus', function() {
  number--;
  if (number < 0) {
    number++;
  } else {
    $(this).text = number;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
Total Number of Tickets : 4
</h3>
<i class="minus">Minus</i>
<div class="quantity">Adult :
  <span class="num"> 0</span>
</div>
<i class="minus">Minus</i>
<div class="quantity">Student :
  <span class="num"> 0</span>
</div>
<i class="minus">Minus</i>
<div class="quantity">Senior :
  <span class="num"> 0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you ask. Try to formulate a better question than *"have no idea how to make it all work together and also to minus. can anyone help me with this?"*

Comment: @Adelin I think its kinda easy to understand what he means, special if you run hes demo

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Depends on what you want to answer. I didn't want to provide code with no explanation. I wanted to provide an answer that OP will understand

Comment: @Adelin well I think its childish of you to downvote my answer just because I didn't agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should work the way you want it.

```
var quantity = 4;
var number = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.num', function() {
  var thisnumber = $(this).text();
  if (number < quantity) {
    number++;
    $(this).text(parseInt(thisnumber) + 1)
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.minus, .fa-minus', function() {
  var thisnumber = $(this).next().find(".num").text();
  if (number > 0) {
    number--;
    $(this).next().find(".num").text(parseInt(thisnumber) - 1)
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var quantity = 4;
var number = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.num', function() {
  var thisnumber = $(this).text();
  if (number < quantity) {
    number++;
    $(this).text(parseInt(thisnumber) + 1)
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.minus, .fa-minus', function() {
  var thisnumber = $(this).next().find(".num").text();
  if (number > 0) {
    number--;
    $(this).next().find(".num").text(parseInt(thisnumber) - 1)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
  Total Number of Tickets : 4
</h3>
<i class="minus">Minus</i>
<div class="quantity">Adult :
  <span class="num"> 0</span>
</div>
<i class="minus">Minus</i>
<div class="quantity">Student :
  <span class="num"> 0</span>
</div>
<i class="minus">Minus</i>
<div class="quantity">Senior :
  <span class="num"> 0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @shikiko No problem, happy to help

Comment: I downvoted not because you didn't agree (funny you'd think that), but because **this answer is not useful**. This answer lacks a proper explanation as to why OP's code didn't work and why this works, and also an answer like this encourages OP to just go ahead and ask, instead of trying to figure out the proper algorithm himself. A good answer is not defined by the fact that *it works*, but by the fact that OP and others will thereafter be able to come up with the solution themselves.

Comment: Being not familiar with jquery, i am not clear with its syntax and actually figured out why my code wasnt able to change the text but with the answer provided it actually showed/taught me how to approach if i were to face another problem like this. I don't see whats wrong with him just posting an answer and leaving it up to the OP to learn . I would do the same if i were in his position

Comment: And that's fine. I think it's not useful, I downvoted, others think is useful, they upvoted. That's fine. I just answered him why he didn't get my upvote, but a downvote instead.